# How to enter two commands in pig gruntshell without typing enter key?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, grunt-shell

```
A = LOAD '/pig/student.tsv' as (rollno:int, name:chararray, gpa:float);
DUMP A;
```

If I want to execute the first line, I have to type Enter key after the first line.

How can I make it as a single execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pig script file to make it as single execution.

**test.pig**

```
A = LOAD '/pig/student.tsv' as (rollno:int, name:chararray, gpa:float); 
DUMP A;
```

Now run the pig script using below command from pig/bin,

```
pig -f /path/test.pig
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pig script(say, `myscript.pig`) containing those 2 lines. Then, run this script using the command `pig myscript.pig`

Answer (score 0):

Short-answer, use a script as suggested by [Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338492/how-to-enter-two-commands-in-pig-gruntshell-without-typing-enter-key#answer-37338653).

Long answer, if you create a single line script containing multiple statements, then it will be not be long before it becomes a nightmare to read and understand as your script grows. Having said that, if you use a script, it won't matter whether you use one line or multiple lines.

So, my suggestion will be to use a [well-indented](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079) script for learning/development/what-have-you.